# Nested dynamic routing in API is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to get the details of a product from the category of products. My folder structure is looking like:

[image]

In "productId/index.jsx" => This is my code to get the single product details:

```
const ProductDetails = ({ data }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
//   const { productId } = router.query;
  console.log(data, "data");
  return <div>ProductDetails</div>;
};

export default ProductDetails;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const _ApiService = new ApiServices();
  const response = await _ApiService.getAllProducts();
  const data = await response;
  const paths = data.data.map((item) => {
    return {
      params: {
        productId: item.id.toString(),
      },
    };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const id = params.productId;
  const _ApiService = new ApiServices();
  const response = await _ApiService.getProduct(id);
  const data = await response;
  return {
    props: {
      data: data.data,
    },
  };
}
```

But when I run this, it is throwing me the error:

> "Error: A required parameter (categoryId) was not provided as a string received undefined in getStaticPaths for /products/[categoryId]/[productId]"

I've also tested the API separately, It is working fine and also the product Id query is received correctly in the page. I've used the same code for `[categoryId]/index.jsx` to fetch the single category but `categoryId` word instead of `productId`. It worked well.

Comment: In think in `params` in `getStaticPaths`, you need to set `categoryId` as you did for `productId`.

Comment: It is not working since the file name is [productId].js @YoussoufOumar

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by sending the "categoryId" along with the "productId" as we use nested slugs here. After changing my getStaticPaths looks like,

```
  const _ApiService = new ApiServices();
  const response = await _ApiService.getAllProducts();
  const data = await response;
  const paths = data.data.map((item) => {
    return {
      params: {
        productId: item.id.toString(),
        categoryId: item.category.toString()
      },
    };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```